# What is the name of this type of chair that can be found on beaches?

Tags: translation, single-word-request, french

I'm looking for a German translation of this type of chair, that can be found on the northern French beaches. We call them "Chaises à capuchon", where *chaise* is "chair" and *capuchon* would be "hood" or "cap".

I couldn't find that word used in German on the Internet, an approximate realistic translation would be highly appreciated.

[image: Chaise à capuchon]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> der Strandkorb

The literal translation is *beach basket* — which should be pretty obvious if you look at it, and where it is usually found. They are extremely common on beaches on the North Sea in Germany, where weather and wind are usually even worse than on northern French beaches.

Comment: Wieso »Korb«? Ein Korb ist doch sowas: http://www.worldwidespirits.de/cosmoshop/default/pix/a/n/1_33813_36319.jpeg

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Schon, aber ein Korb ist eben zunächst auch sowas: https://www.otto.de/p/butlers-hamlet-rattan-korb-gross-365406331/#variationId=-14539805 (wobei wir schon näher an der Form dran wären), und daneben bezeichnet *Korb* auch das Material an sich (für Beispiele durchsuche das Web bitte nach "aus Korb").

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Die Materialbezeichnung »Korb« ist mir völlig neu, die Google-Suche belehrt mich aber, dass diese Bezeichnung tatsächlich Verwendung findet, wenn auch nicht rasend häufig. Google behauptet nämlich bei der Suche nach »"aus Korb"« 81.600 Treffer zu finden, bei »"aus Holz"« sind es hingegen 13.200.000 Treffer, also ca 162-mal so viele.

Comment: Als Korb hätte ich bisher grundsätzlich nur einen oben offenen Behälter aus geflochtenem Material bezeichnet, der eventuell auch einen Deckel haben kann. Optional ist ein Henkel, an dem man diesen Behälter tragen kann. Das umfasst einen Einkaufskorb und einen Wäschekorb. Auch eine geflochtene Bütte/Putte, in der man früher Holz sammelte (oder in die der Krampus die schlimmen Kinder steckt) würde in diese Definition fallen. Davon abgeleitet auch das »Tor« beim Basketball, den Gesichtsschutz beim Fechten und (als auf dem Kopf stehender Korb) die Behausung für ein Bienenvolk kenne ich als Korb

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: "die Google-Suche belehrt mich aber, dass diese Bezeichnung tatsächlich Verwendung findet, wenn auch nicht rasend häufig. (...)" - ungeachtet des Umstands, ob das nun eine häufige Bezeichnung für dieses Material ist oder nicht, gibt es vermutlich einfach viel mehr Dinge aus Holz als Dinge aus Korb.

Comment: You find the Strankorb also at the North Sea, but it was invented at the Baltic Sea (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strandkorb).

Answer (score 15):

In German that is a [Strandkorb](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strandkorb).

A two-part hooded chair, traditionally made of wicker, that provides shelter from wind and sand and is a common beach accessoire on both the German North Sea and Baltic Sea beaches. Typically they are available for rent there, as they are too unwieldy to lug around.

Comment: I don’t understand French, but it seems that they are called *Strandkorb* in French, too, at least according to [their Wikipedia article about it](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strandkorb "French Wikipedia: 'Strandkorb'") (edit: oh, and [in English, too](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strandkorb "English Wikipedia: 'Strandkorb'")).

Comment: and in Italian, Lithuanian and even Turkish... looks like it was a German invention... didn't know that.